# ReactJS Dynamically Replace Children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a fancy UI in which have a few 'panes' with dividers in between that let you change what each one does. Say I have two different components - a to-do list and a simple text editor. I want you to be able to change the component present in each pane to make a flexible UI. For example, I might want to change the pane on the left from a text editor to a to-do list. Assuming I have a parent element `Pane`, how could I replace one of its children with another?

```
<Pane>
    <TextEditor /> /* I want to replace that with a <ToDoList /> when I press a button */
    <SomeOtherComponentOnTheRight />
</Pane>
```

I've tried storing `React.Children.toArray(this.props.children)` in the `<Pane />`'s state (as `this.state.currentChildren`), and replacing the element there, but for some reason I can't find a way to get the index of `<TextEditor />` in the `<Pane />`'s `this.state.currentChildren` because for some reason `this.props.children` does not preserve children's props, and so I can't transmit data through it.

Sorry if I've overcomplicated this, but I simply want to know how to change a component's children dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

You could check the state in your JSX to change what is displayed such as:

```
<Pane>
    { this.state.showEditor ? <TextEditor/> : <ToDoList /> }
    <SomeOtherComponentOnTheRight />
</Pane>
```

Elsewhere in your code you would have some button that invokes an onClick event handler that would set the state of 'showEditor' to true/false depending on the previous state.

Comment: Would that create a new `<ToDoList />` element every time it is rerendered? If so, that could be a problem because it's a stateful component.

Comment: @Tobsta yes it would. If you want to maintain the state of the component then instead of toggling components why don't you just do something like toggle `{ hidden: !app.state.showEditor }` in the component's style attribute? That will keep the component but toggle its visibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the selected components in an array or object, then assign the selected component to a variable (just make sure it starts with an uppercase letter) and then use it as a component:

```
const routes = {
    a: TextEditor,
    b: ToDoList
};

const ChosenComponent = routes['a']; // select your component and store in variable

return (
    <Pane>
        <ChosenComponent />
        <SomeOtherComponentOnTheRight /> {/* render selected variable as component */}
    </Pane>
);
```